# Certbot for multiserver configuration

Tags: letsencrypt, certbot

Is there a way to use certbot and letsencrypt certificate for multiserver setup without having to manually copy the certificates from one node to another?

I have a domain name `example.com` which is resolved to 192.0.2.1 in Americas and to 192.0.2.2 in Asia.

I run certbot from American server and it successfully generates certificate.
I can't run the same command from Asian server, as certbot will be able to resolve domain only to 192.0.2.1.

Therefore in order to install certificate for Asian server I have to copy it from 192.0.2.1 to 192.0.2.2.

Yes, the copy process can be scripted, though it doesn't look like a good idea for me. Is there other way around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I used solution [described here](https://arrfab.net/posts/2016/May/03/generating-multiple-certificates-with-letsencrypt-from-a-single-instance/).

In a couple of words:

1. Use a single node for certificate generation
2. Use nginx proxy to forward /.well-known/ from all frontends to the node from step 1
3. Copy with scripts certificates to all frontend servers

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you can't know where the verification will run from.

You have a two general solutions:

1. copy the cert+key between the servers.
2. temporarily have your domain resolve to exactly one place, issue a cert there, then make it resolve to the other location and issue a cert there, lastly flip back to your split horizon. You'll have to repeat this when you want to renew the certificate as well.

Solution 2 is far worse practice than copying your cert+key.

Consider how you would have solved this prior to LetsEncrypt:

- generate a key & CSR somewhere (admin workstation or a server)
- submit CSR to CA
- get cert back from CA
- push key & cert to both servers.

From that perspective, pushing the key/cert from one server to the other isn't that bad.

This was also covered previously:
https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/will-lets-encrypt-work-for-me-multiple-servers-serving-one-domain/6830/7